# Combination of selector and condition

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have a very complex condition built with PredicateBuilder but now to use this I need to combine this with field selector to use inside Where clause.

Example:

```
class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmsszz");
        }

        public string Test { get; set; }
    }

    class B
    {
        public A AProp { get; set; } 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(_ => new B())
            .ToList();

        var result = list
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(GetFilter(b => b.AProp))
            .ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<B, bool>> GetFilter(Expression<Func<B, A>> selector)
    {
        // some complex condition to apply on property AProp 
        Expression<Func<A, bool>> condition = a => a.Test.Contains("2015");

        return b => true; // Like b.AProp.Test.Contains("2015");
    }
```

Limitations:

- B can be any generic type
- The condition is really complicated
- Should be simple enough to pass through NHibernate.Linq and to get SQL

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: Please apply condition to result of selector and return this as result GetFilter method.

Comment: Still not clear, you'll get better help if you make it more obvious what you're trying to ask